# Как оптимизировать код

Tags: php

Имею следующее одоробло:

```
function lpt($input)
{
    $text = array();
    static $langs = array("", "az", "sq", "am", "en", "ar", "hy", "af", "eu", "ba", "be", "bn", "my", "bg", "bs", "cy", "hu", "vi", "ht", "gl", "nl", "mrj", "el", "ka", "gu", "da", "he", "yi", "id", "ga", "it", "is", "es", "kk", "kn", "ca", "ky", "zh", "ko", "xh", "km", "lo", "la", "lv", "lt", "lb", "mg", "ms", "ml", "mt", "mk", "mi", "mr", "mhr", "mn", "de", "ne", "no", "pa", "pap", "fa", "pl", "pt", "ro", "ru", "ceb", "sr", "si", "sk", "sl", "sw", "su", "tg", "th", "tl", "ta", "tt", "te", "tr", "udm", "uz", "uk", "ur", "fi", "fr", "hi", "hr", "cs", "sv", "gd", "et", "eo", "jv", "ja");
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++)
    {
        $text[$i] = substr($input, $i, 1);
    }
    foreach($text as $val)
    {
        $ln = rand(1, 93);
        $query = file_get_contents("https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=trnsl.1.1.20170527T132437Z.c57c2dbe7e627169.5d32134e6f999da05a22423940d40ccc96e3ac94&text=".$text[$val]."&lang=".$langs[$ln]."");
        $rest = json_decode($query, true);
        $letter = $rest['text'];
        $hash = crypt($letter[0]);
        $go .= $hash;
    }
    unset($val);
    $finhash = md5(crypt($input));
    return $finhash;
}
```

Имеет смысл его оптимизировать или к монахам переписывать?
Просто в оптимизации полный ноль, а то, шо дофига грузит - немного напрягает

Comment: А код точно работает? Меня смущают два фрагмента: `$text as $val` и `$text[$val]`. Просто `foreach` в такой форме это цикл уже по значениям. Потом почему-то значение используется как индекс в том же массиве.

Comment: А, это шуточный вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

У вас каждый раз вычисляется условие, а нужно один раз. Нужно исправить это:

```
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++)
```

на это:

```
for($i = 0, $l = strlen($input); $i < $l; $i++)
```

Comment: Мне всё таки кажется, шо это выйдет масло масляное, только в более растопленом виде. Может я чего-то не знаю, но всё равно...

Comment: @Артем Добряк, монахи в помощь)) Кстити спасибо, мне ваш код помог ответить на мой вопрос.

Comment: @АртемДобряк рекомендую прислушаться к этому совету. Это сейчас у вас код небольшой, и отжирает немного памяти. А если это будет крупный проект, или будут обрабатываться большие массивы данных какой-то функцией, наподобие вашей, то у вас просто может не хватить ОЗУ из-за подобной мелочи. :)

Comment: @АртемДобряк, нужно сохранять размер до итерации или в начале, как сделал `John Smit Conor`. Сделайте 5 миллионов прогонов, поймете.

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему, вашу функцию можно оптимизировать следующим образом:

```
function lpt($input) {
    return md5(crypt($input));
}
```

Comment: Нет, тогда теряется весь цимес шифра

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++)
{
    $text[$i] = substr($input, $i, 1);
}
foreach($text as $val)
{
```

можно заменить на

```
foreach((array)$input as $val)
{
```

а фрагмент `$text[$val]` или ошибочен и нужен просто `$val`, либо когда-то вывалится за диапазон элементов

`unset($val);` не нужен.
как впрочем и всё что выше...